# Error executing IBM DB2 Stored Proceedure in EJB container

Tags: java, stored-procedures, db2, ejb-3.0

I'm getting the error below when i try to execute a stored procedure in a Stateless bean with container managed persistance;

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-751, SQLSTATE=38003, SQLERRMC=STORED PROCEDURE;FXTR324;FXTR324;COMMIT, DRIVER=4.7.85
```

The stored proc executes without errors if i manually create the connection the database, i.e. unmanaged transaction.

Is there anything i need to do for it to execute in the EJB bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set transaction attribute to NotSupported for method that calls stored procedure. This way you will make sure that your method is executed without active transaction context (active one will be suspended) thus your stored procedure (which presumably does commit/rollback logic) will be successfully executed.

For more info take a look at [this article](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/dw/java/j-ts2-pdf.pdf).

Comment: thanks for the doc link. I tried `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` but it still failed. It turns out this is caused by my datasource configuration on JBoss. I'm using an `xa-datasource` which by defination is a *global transaction*. I created a `local-datasource` and the issue is now resovled.